# Managed Metadata column resolves the name by looking only at the beginning of the name..?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata

We are runnig on SharePoint 2010 and have created a site column of the type Managed Metadata, When we enter a name that exists in the Global metadata, e.g. "Check", it is not resolved because the whole name is “IP Check” and therefore it resolves the name by looking only at the beginning of the name.

So it is possible to configure the Managed Metadata property to suggest if the given word is at least a part of the term? instead of suggesting only the terms that starts with the provided word.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't, one workaround would be to define synonyms for terms that are particularly problematic.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-manage-terms-within-term-sets-HA101631581.aspx#_Toc266880363